# NASM x86_64, Redifining Labels

Tags: label, nasm

My Goal is to redifine an existing label in the .data section of my Nasm Code.

The expected result shoud be that the existing memory label gets overwritten by the same procedure

The occuring errormessages are:

```
exp3.asm:230: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand

exp3.asm:191: ... from macro `var' defined here

exp3.asm:230: warning: character constant too long

exp3.asm:191: ... from macro `var' defined here

exp3.asm:230: error: parser: instruction expected

exp3.asm:195: ... from macro `var' defined here

exp3.asm:231: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand

exp3.asm:191: ... from macro `var' defined here

exp3.asm:231: error: symbol `test' redefined

exp3.asm:195: ... from macro `var' defined here

exp3.asm:231: error: parser: instruction expected

exp3.asm:195: ... from macro `var' defined here
```

Ive tried to rearange the word types, but it just complicated the problem instead of solving it.

The Required Macros:

```
%macro ifexis 3
    push rax ; make room
    mov rax, %1 ; platziere wert in Vergleichsregister
    test rax, rax ; wenn werte gleich oder nicht leer
    jz [%2] ; Gehe zu erfolg
    jmp [%3] ; gehe zu fail
    pop rax ; clear rax
%endmacro
```

Checks if the value exists by loading the Contents in to RAX and then testing it against eachother

```
    %macro var 2
        ifexis %1, %%overwrite, %%establish  ;<--------------------------------------- Für gleiche labels muss eine lösung gefunden werden
        %%overwrite: ;<---------------------------------------------------------------
        mov db[%1], %2 ;<-------------------------------------------------------------
        jmp %%end;<-------------------------------------------------------------------
        %%establish:;<----------------------------------------------------------------
        section .data
        %1: db %2
        ;db 0
        section .text
        %%end:
%endmacro
```

Test code:

```
section .text 
global _start
_start:
 var test, "a"
 var test, "b"
```

Any aditional sources for learning Assembler are welcome

Comment: What is `mov db[%1], %2` supposed to mean? In any case, I don't see anything in the NASM manual suggesting that what you're trying to do is supported. Why would you even need this?

Comment: Its supposed to get the mem adress and then overwrite it, i adjusted it you were right error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand is now solved

Comment: But now the overwrite still is shown in nasm